# Cannot select location or pricing tier in FormRecognizer Preview

Tags: azure, preview, azure-cognitive-services

I registered for the FormRecognizer public preview and I'm having trouble creating a resource in my Azure environment. I received the welcome email today with the instructions to follow, but when I try to create a FormRecognizer resource in Azure the Location and Pricing dropdowns do not have any selectable options. These fields are required so I cannot create this resource. I have verified that I'm on the Azure subscription that I used to request being part of this Preview Program.

Any ideas? Do I have to wait a certain amount of time (say 24 hrs?) before it will work? Any help is appreciated.

I've tried on multiple browsers (Chrome, Edge) and all have the same issue.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my issue. For those interested the subscription ID that was registered was different than the one I was trying to access Form Recognizer with. MS corrected when I provided them the correct subscription ID and now all is working.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely has only been rolled out to a single or limited number of regions, and while it's in preview you're probably not being charged for it.