# Azure Cognitive Services - Not able to select location or pricing tier in Form Recognizer

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I'm trying to create a Form recognizer resource and got welcome mail. But I'm not able to select the location while creating my resource from Azure Portal.I an using correct subscription ID which i gave at registration time.

[image: Azure form recognizer]

Comment: Check this one -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58564222/cannot-select-location-or-pricing-tier-in-formrecognizer-preview

Comment: Make sure the subscription you are selecting in the dropdown is authorized to access the form recognition feature as it's under preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be an Azure subscription issue , raising a subscription support ticket from Azure portal will be a good idea .Details refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) .